# Qualifying exam question concerning roots of equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Consider a polynomial $f_n(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+...+a_n$ with integer coefficients. If $f_n(x_i)=19$ for $5$ distinct $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, find the number of distinct integer solutions for $f_n(x)=23$?

My attempt: Clearly $f_n(x)$ has integer solutions for any $f_n(x)=integer$ (Since it has integral coefficients and $x_n$ has coefficient 1). If $f_n(x_i)=19$ has 5 integral solutions, $f_n(x)=23$ should have the same, unless there are some new wiggles in between y= 19 and y=23 or some old ones die in between. How do I confirm this? My guess is that somehow this integral coefficient thing may not be allowing for such wiggles.

Comment: I guess the key is that the roots are algebraic integers, and hence they are either integers or not rational.

Comment: @Easy: Why couldn't they be non-real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ f(x) = (x\!-\!n_1)\cdots (x\!-\!n_5)\,g(x)\!+\! 19 = 23\:\Rightarrow\:(x\!-\!n_1)\cdots(x\!-\!n_5)\,g(x) = 4.\:$ But at most two  $\rm\:|x-n_i| = 1,\:$ so the other three have magnitude $\ge 2,\,$ so $\,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks. Suppose $x-n_1=1$, $x-n_2=-1$, the choices left are either one of rest 3 roots are $\pm 4$, or two of them are 2 and -2. Anyways I will be getting 5 distinct roots since all $n_i$ are distinct. Am I correct? I just have a problem visualizing it.

Comment: @Uma Can three integers of magnitude $\ge 2$ have product dividing $4$?

Comment: No. But here is my doubt suppose $x-n_1=1$, $x-n_2=-1$, $x-n_3=2$, $x-n_4=-2$ and $x-n_5=1$. This satisfies the above equation. So $x=1+n_1,-1+n_2, 2+n_3, -2+n_4 and 1+n_5$ which might be distinct I suppose. Sorry to bother you but I haven't done much number theory, and have a problem visualizing here.

Comment: @Uma Recall that the $\rm\:n_i\:$ are distinct, so $\rm\: x-n_i\:$ are distinct, so the value $\,1\,$ cannot occur twice.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. Now thinking ahead (this might be a bit philosophical), suppose I have a equation of degree 5 satisfying the above condition. The graph of f(x) will have 2 hills and 2 valleys. The line y=19 cuts these hills and valleys at 5 points. When I draw y=23, I loose one root(which I derive from number theory) i.e. the line must be touching one of the hill tops and cutting the rest. Is there a connection between these different approaches?(I mean mathematically)

Answer (score 0):

Factorising $f_n(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_m)g(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)$ irreducible. Notice that $19$ is a prime number and is a product of the factors of $f_n(x)$, so the possible factors are $\pm1,\pm19$. And notice that $23$ is also a prime number...